# Org-reveal: Make 'data-background-interactive' optional when using iframe backgrounds

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

Currently, when setting an iframe as a background, the resulting html has the attribute `data-background-interactive` enabled by default

```
** Iframe test
:PROPERTIES:
:reveal_background_iframe: https://example.com
:END:
```

will be exported as:

```
<section>
<section id="slide-org7bae297" data-background-iframe="https://example.com" data-background-interactive>
<div style="">
    <h2 id="org7bae297">Iframe test</h2>
</div>
</section>
</section>
```

In the `ox-reveal.el` file the corresponding section tag is coded as follows (line 456)

```
...
(format "<section %s data-background-interactive>\n<div %s>\n"
...
```

Is there a way to modify it so it will become an optional argument?

Comment: Yes, Org has a built-in command for submitting RFEs like this as well as bug reports: `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. The devs will get back to you fairly soon with any questions they need answered or with some kind of answer as to whether they think your request is feasible and desirable or if there is some reason it couldn't/shouldn't be implemented. They are patient and helpful and highly skilled and will usually say yes if they can. Please bear in mind that they are volunteers and do everything you can to help them clearly understand the precise change you are asking for.